# Icecast2 make point to connect Rivendell

Tags: streaming, live, icecast, internet-radio, mount-point

I have server with option SSH to run own proces. On this server I have preinstaled command `icecast` and `ices`.

I want to create in IceCast mount point to connect to them by Rivendell. But after read many pages w examples I haven't idea why Icecast can't make mounting point. After run ices, I have log `No playlist type given` - but I want only mounting point, not playlist player.

```
$ icecast
Icecast 2.4.4

usage: icecast [-b] -c <file>
or   : icecast {-v|--version}
options:
        -c <file>       Specify configuration file
        -v or --version Display version info
        -b              Run icecast in the background

$ ices
IceS 2.0.3
  (c) Copyright 2001-2020 The IceS Development Team <team@icecast.org>
        Michael Smith   <msmith@icecast.org>
        Jack Moffitt    <jack@icecast.org>
        Karl Heyes      <karl@xiph.org>
        Philipp Schafft <lion@lion.leolix.org>
        and others

Usage: "ices config.xml"

Using libshout 2.4.5
```

I run both command i separate process:

```
$ icecast -c /icecast/icecast.xml
[2023-03-05  10:00:20] WARN fserve/fserve_recheck_mime_types Cannot open mime types file /etc/mime.types

$ ices /icecast/icecast-playlist.xml
[2023-03-05  10:02:01] INFO ices-core/main IceS 2.0.3 started...
[2023-03-05  10:02:01] EROR playlist-builtin/playlist_open_module No playlist type given, cannot initialise playlist module
[2023-03-05  10:02:01] EROR input/input_loop Couldn't initialise input module "playlist"
[2023-03-05  10:02:01] INFO ices-core/main Shutdown complete
```

But I don't see mounting point.
[image: Icecast page]

Where I make mistake?

`icecast.xml`:

```
<icecast>
    <!-- location and admin are two arbitrary strings that are e.g. visible
         on the server info page of the icecast web interface
         (server_version.xsl). -->
    <location>WORLD</location>
    <admin>contact@example.com</admin>

    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>2</sources>
        <threadpool>5</threadpool>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client 
             first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup 
             time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
             it also significantly increases latency between the source
             client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
             might want to disable this. -->
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
             specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
             change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>hackme</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>hackme</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>hackme</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
         specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
         wanted or an extension is required
    <shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->
    <!--
    <directory>
        <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
        <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
    </directory>
     -->

    <!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
    It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
    listings. -->
    <hostname>audio.example.com</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>6000</port>
        <bind-address>0.0.0.0</bind-address>
        <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
    </listen-socket>
    
    <mount>
    <bitrate>128</bitrate>
    <mount-name>/mp3</mount-name>
    <fallback-override>0</fallback-override>
    <fallback-when-full>0</fallback-when-full>
    <public>1</public>
    <max-listeners>150</max-listeners>
    <fallback-mount></fallback-mount>
    <genre>alternative</genre>
    <type>audio/mpeg</type>
  </mount>

  <mount>
    <bitrate>64</bitrate>
    <mount-name>/mobile</mount-name>
    <fallback-override>0</fallback-override>
    <fallback-when-full>0</fallback-when-full>
    <public>1</public>
    <max-listeners>50</max-listeners>
    <fallback-mount></fallback-mount>
  </mount>
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8001</port>
    </listen-socket>
    -->

    <!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
    <!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
    <!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
    <!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

    <!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
         useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
         The default is 0 -->
    <!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

    <!--
    <relay>
        <server>127.0.0.1</server>
        <port>8001</port>
        <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
        <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>

        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
    -->

    <!-- Only define a <mount> section if you want to use advanced options,
         like alternative usernames or passwords
<mount>
 <mount-name>/test</mount-name>
   </mount>
   <mount>
        <mount-name>/autodj</mount-name>
        <hidden>0</hidden>
   </mount>
   <mount>
        <mount-name>/live</mount-name>
        <fallback-mount>/autodj</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <hidden>0</hidden>
   </mount>
   <mount>
        <mount-name>/listen</mount-name>
        <fallback-mount>/live</fallback-mount>
       <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <hidden>0</hidden>
   </mount>
     -->
     
     <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/test.ogg</mount-name>

        <username>othersource</username>
        <password>hackmemore</password>

        <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
        <dump-file>/stream/test01.ogg</dump-file>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        <fallback-mount>/test01.ogg</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
        <public>1</public>

    </mount>

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
        <basedir>/icecast/</basedir>

        <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
             be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
        <logdir>/icecast/</logdir>
        <webroot>/icecast/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/icecast/admin</adminroot>
        <!-- <pidfile>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pid</pidfile> -->

        <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
             May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
             and "bind-address" attributes.
          -->
        <!--
        <alias source="/foo" destination="/bar"/>
          -->
        <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
             this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
             the status page
          -->
        <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
        <loglevel>4</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
        <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
             the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
             otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
             Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
        -->
        <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <chroot>0</chroot>
        <!--
        <changeowner>
            <user>nobody</user>
            <group>nogroup</group>
        </changeowner>
        -->
    </security>
</icecast>
```

`ices-playlist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ices>
    <!-- run in background -->
    <background>0</background>
    <!-- where logs, etc go. -->
    <logpath>/icecast/</logpath>
    <logfile>ices.log</logfile>
    <!-- 1=error,2=warn,3=info,4=debug -->
    <loglevel>3</loglevel>
    <!-- set this to 1 to log to the console instead of to the file above -->
    <consolelog>1</consolelog>

    <!-- optional filename to write process id to -->
    <!-- <pidfile>/home/ices/ices.pid</pidfile> -->

    <stream>
        <!-- metadata used for stream listing (not currently used) -->
        <metadata>
            <name>Example stream name</name>
            <genre>Example genre</genre>
            <description>A short description of your stream</description>
        </metadata>

        <!-- input module

            The module used here is the playlist module - it has
            'submodules' for different types of playlist. There are
            two currently implemented, 'basic', which is a simple
            file-based playlist, and 'script' which invokes a command
            to returns a filename to start playing. -->


                <!-- Stream instance
            You may have one or more instances here. This allows you to
            send the same input data to one or more servers (or to different
            mountpoints on the same server). Each of them can have different
            parameters. This is primarily useful for a) relaying to multiple
            independent servers, and b) encoding/reencoding to multiple
            bitrates.
            If one instance fails (for example, the associated server goes
            down, etc), the others will continue to function correctly.
            This example defines two instances as two mountpoints on the
            same server.  -->
        <instance>
            <!-- Server details:
                You define hostname and port for the server here, along with
                the source password and mountpoint.  -->
            <hostname>localhost</hostname>
            <port>6000</port>
            <password>hackme</password>
            <mount>/mp3</mount>

            <!-- Reconnect parameters:
                When something goes wrong (e.g. the server crashes, or the
                network drops) and ices disconnects from the server, these
                control how often it tries to reconnect, and how many times
                it tries to reconnect. Delay is in seconds.
                If you set reconnectattempts to -1, it will continue
                indefinately. Suggest setting reconnectdelay to a large value
                if you do this.
            -->
            <reconnectdelay>2</reconnectdelay>
            <reconnectattempts>5</reconnectattempts>

            <!-- maxqueuelength:
                This describes how long the internal data queues may be. This
                basically lets you control how much data gets buffered before
                ices decides it can't send to the server fast enough, and
                either shuts down or flushes the queue (dropping the data)
                and continues.
                For advanced users only.
            -->
            <maxqueuelength>80</maxqueuelength>

            <!-- Live encoding/reencoding:
                Currrently, the parameters given here for encoding MUST
                match the input data for channels and sample rate. That
                restriction will be relaxed in the future.
            -->
            <encode>
                <nominal-bitrate>64000</nominal-bitrate> <!-- bps. e.g. 64000 for 64 kbps -->
                <samplerate>44100</samplerate>
                <channels>2</channels>
            </encode>
        </instance>

        </stream>
</ices>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ices is only used if you want to play out a playlist with it.  It's a source client.  If you are using a different source client, then configure it.

The mount point will appear once the source client is running.